# Good online resources for Microsoft Dynamics SL?

Tags: sql-server, accounting, dynamics-sl

Does anyone know of good online resources for Microsoft Dynamics SL (Solomon)?  I'm interested in general support information and back end SQL support information, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I've found is [the Microsoft Dynamics SL Community](http://community.dynamics.com/sl/home.aspx).